# H2 JDBC Function "NVARCHAR" not found

Tags: h2

I'm trying to write an integration test for a repository on a SQL Server request.

I'm using an H2 database and I get an exception :

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Function "NVARCHAR" not found

I guess because H2 doesn't know `NVARCHAR` type as there is no mention of it in their documentation.
https://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html

Is there a way to make work a SQL Server request with `NVARCHAR` with H2?

(Like declaring a `NVARCHAR` function and make it return a static value for example as I'm only using `NVARCHAR(max)`)

My request looks like :

```
SELECT 
  STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(field1,'')), ',') as field1, 
  STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), ISNULL(field2,'')), ',') as field2
FROM my_table;
```

Comment: The corresponding data type of (the non-standard) `nvarchar(max)` would be `CLOB`. But `nvarchar` is a data type, not a function, so it's unclear why you try to use it as a function to begin with.

Comment: [Don't use In-Memory Databases for Tests](https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/)

Comment: Nice reading, I completely agree thats it's better to use a docker image of a real database. I'll try to move to it if there is no quickest solution.

Comment: The SQL standard equivalent of the proprietary `convert()` function would be `cast(... as clob)` which works in H2 as well I think

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're right it works with H2 !

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name But it no longer works in Microsoft SQL Server... -_-